# Why is only one UIEvent created for many separate touches?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, events, uitouch, uievent

I'm learning the touch event mechanism of iOS.

From the documentation I understood that a `UIEvent` object would be created when first touch down happened, it would live till the last touch up, and it would contain all the `UITouch` objects created in the period.

But in my testing, I found that there is only one `UIEvent` object created in a view in whole life of the application, and the number of `UITouch` objects it contains depends on how many fingers touch.

If you touch with one finger, there would be only one `UITouch` object created, and the `UITouch` object would be updated in different phases.

I mean the representation in my testing is different from the description of the documentation: there is only one `UIEvent` object when many different touches happen.

Why is that? Have I misunderstood something anywhere?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DtdDJM7SI0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event is an action or occurrence detected by the program that may be handled by the program. The event could be anything like touch event, motion event or remote-control event.
 Simply `UITouch` also is an **part of** `UIEvent`. UITouch can generate event which is handled by program. Program sense the touch using event.

For more detail information you get in following links,
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_%28computing%29

I hope it will helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue. It really confuses me that the UIEvent object with the same memory address appears again and again -*-. According to my understanding, each time a multi-touch sequence happens, a UIEvent will be created to represent it. I tend to think this way: Each time there only be one multi-touch sequence occuring, so only one UIEvent object can represent all of them through the whole life of the app. ^*^

Answer (score 0):

Below links might be usefull your query.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html